# Virtualenvwrapper not installed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenvwrapper but when I run `which virtualenvwrapper` I get nothing.
When I try to do a reinstall using `pip3`, here's what I get.

```
~: $ pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenvwrapper in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv-clone in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): stevedore in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
Cleaning up...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: how are you trying to use it?

Comment: You're not supposed to get anything. Try `mkvirtualenv` and `work on`. Also, install the script in your `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing [`virtualenvwrapper`](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), you need to

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

to get these functions (such as `virtualenvwrapper`, `mkvirtualenv`, `cdvirtualenv`, ...).

To make it permanent, just put two lines above to your `~/.bashrc` file.